# Непонимаю что написано про память в книге Таненбаума

Tags: память, железо

Читаю книгу Таненбаума Компьютерная архтитектура,
начал читать про память и тут:

> В компьютерах, в которых используется двоичная система счисления (включая восьмеричное и шестнадцатеричное представление двоичных чисел), адреса
>       памяти также выражаются в двоичных числах. Если адрес состоит из m бит,
>       максимальное число адресуемых ячеек составит 2m. Например, адрес для обращения к памяти, изображенной на рис. 2.8, а, должен состоять по крайней мере
>       из 4 бит, чтобы выражать все числа от 0 до 11. При устройстве памяти, показанном на рис. 2.8, б и 2.8, в, достаточно 3-разрядного адреса. Число битов в адресе
>       определяет максимальное количество адресуемых ячеек памяти и не зависит от
>       числа битов в ячейке. 12-разрядные адреса нужны и памяти из 212 ячеек по 8 бит
>       каждая, и памяти из 2^12 ячеек по 64 бит каждая.
>   Он имеет ввиду что адрес(номер ячейки) должен быть 4-битным или 3-битным чтобы адресоваться на ячейки или что?

Я запутался тут:

> Число битов в адресе определяет максимальное количество адресуемых ячеек памяти и не зависит от числа битов в ячейке

Ну типо ячейка имеет адрес и в ячейке кол-во байт, и потом: и не зависит от числа битов в ячейке. Что?

Comment: Имеется ввиду что разрядность ячейки данных не влияет на обьем адресуемого пространства. Т.е. если байт 8 бит, и в одну ячейку можно записать 1 байт (8 бит), то это не означает что процессор не может работать с памятью за пределами 256 байт (8 бит).

Comment: а понял, но как это число битов в адресе?

Comment: @nick_n_a, "адресуемое адресное пространство" как-то не очень звучит. *Адресное просторанство* это и так the range of memory that can be addressed (из мануала Intel).

Comment: @eanmos вижу тавтология, поправил.

Comment: другими словами количество бит в адресе не зависит от количества бит которые лежат по этому адресу

Comment: *но как это* ну вот фраза "12-разрядные адреса" означает что 12 бит в адресе.

Comment: @nick_n_a в том то и прикол что пишеться что адрес должен быть минимум 4-битным при этом если ячеек 12 (и ячейки 8 битны).тоесть как это адрес 4-битный,a ячейки при этом могу быть "любо-битны(ячейка может иметь 8 или 12 или еще сколько-то)"

Comment: @efgdgsDGsg, размер адреса определяет *количество*  ячеек, к которым можно обратиться. Размер *самих ячеек*, от размера адреса не зависит. Все ячейки одинакового размера.

Comment: @eanmos тоесть размер адреса?

Comment: @efgdgsDGsg, не понял вопроса.

Comment: @eanmos  я запутался в понятии РАЗМЕР АДРЕСА и РАЗМЕР ЯЧЕЙКИ или разницы нет?

Comment: Смотря какая у вас задача. *адрес должен быть минимум 4-битным* - это имеется ввиду, что если вы хотите в двоичной системе счисления адресовать 12-ть ячеек памяти - то адрес должен быть 4-х битным.

Comment: @efgdgsDGsg, вся память делится на определенное количество ячеек одинакового размера, называемых *байтами*. Каждая такая ячейка имеет свой номер, называемый *адресом*. Так вот *размер этого адреса* определяет количество доступных для использования ячеек. А размер ячейки может быть абсолютно произвольным.

Comment: тоесть, если у меня доступно 20 ячеек,то размер адреса минимум должен быть 5-битным по скольку в переводе 20 с десятичной системы исчисления в двоичную получаеться 10100(5 цифр, тоесть пятибитный адрес)?

Comment: @efgdgsDGsg, точно!

Comment: @eanmos спасибо! вопрос закрыт!

Answer (score 1):

Вся память делится на определенное количество ячеек одинакового размера, называемых *байтами*. Каждая такая ячейка имеет свой номер, называемый *адресом*. Так вот размер этого адреса определяет количество доступных для использования ячеек. А размер самой ячейки может быть абсолютно произвольным.

Например, если у меня доступно 20 ячеек, то размер адреса должен быть не меньше 5 бит, поскольку при переводе 20<sub>10</sub> из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную получается 10100 (5 разрядов, т. е. пятибитный адрес).